# Add listener on TableView ScrollBar

Tags: java, user-interface, events, javafx, tableview

I want to add a listener on my Tableview ScrollBar and i didn't find this listener in JavaFX.

This is my .FXML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.*?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
    onContextMenuRequested="#showContextMenu">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="300.0"
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" >
            <columns>
                <TableColumn  text="Name">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn  text="Latitude">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn  text="Longitude">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn  text="Label">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Label_two">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Code">
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Code_two">
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

When i add items in TableView a ScrollBar appear automatically, and i want to add on a listener to do specific action when i scroll whith the scrollbar.

The only listener i found :

```
table.setOnScroll(...
table.setOnScrollTo(...
```

... doesn't work or work only if i scroll with the mouse wheel.

How can i solve this ?

EDIT : I captured all Event in the TableView to see which event i have to listen when i scroll with the scrollbar and apparently its a MouseDragged Event that is propagated.

Comment: Possible duplicate look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789525/onscroll-listener-does-not-working-in-tableview-in-javafx-2)

Comment: The solution in this post works only if i scroll with the wheel, not if i scroll with the automatic TableView ScrollBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my workaround with the same issure.
Scrolling the table:

```
table.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, event ->
    PerformYourActionHere
);
```

Drag the scroll bar (I use it with click on TableView "headers" to get sorting event as well)

```
table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
    if ((event.getTarget() instanceof TableColumnHeader) | event.isDragDetect()) {
        PerformYourActionHere
    }         
});
```